# Is the male bee's penis homologous to the female bee's stinger?

Tags: evolution, entomology, anatomy

Considering that when a bee stings it loses its stinger and dies, this is similar to the male drone losing its penis and dying after copulation. It also seems similar that each event basically rips the abdomen open. Are the two structures a homologous pair?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes. Is this question off topic here?

Comment: I didn't downvote it myself, rather I think this is already a good-question, but if properly edited it will be more clear. Are you sure, male-bee's copulation organs called 'penis'? (I don't know). If you know better anatomical terms you could use that.

Comment: Sting and stinger- same thing? Worker bees (modified females) contain sting surely. But does 'female' bees of popular use, i.e queen bees, contain sting?

Comment: Shouldn't be off topic. It actually is a very interesting question. +1 @AlwaysConfused: Of course it's a penis ... what else should it be?

Comment: I don't know terminology but of course bee's that structure is not homologous with mammals' pennis. I don't know exist  there any-other formal term or it is also called penis. Again it was a suggestion not criticism of any sort. I thought it would give the question more 'formal look' to collect upvotes

Comment: In more clear language, the question could be divided into 2 parts. 1. why some  activities kill the bees? 2. since death happens while stinging in worker bees, and copulation in male (drone) bees, could we corelate that these 2  organs (penis and sting) are homologous or not.

Comment: If an asker cannot use a formal term, it is not the asker's fault. It is the viewer's fault.

Comment: really it surprises me why bees need to die when they sting? is it of any benifit? I even fail to find an evolutionary significance.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/45465/16433

Comment: @R.M. thanks for sharing an existing answer to MY question, btw however OP is not at all duplicate with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little bit of digging I was able to find a couple of facts that seem to verify that the drone bee's penis is in fact homologous to the worker bee's stinger:

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinger) about the stinger that says a honey bee's stinger is "a modified ovipositor as in other stinging Hymenoptera".

[This book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=r8H-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&dq=is%20ovipositor%20homologous%20to%20a%20penis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZotCp5ozPAhVN32MKHYyKCoAQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=is%20ovipositor%20homologous%20to%20a%20penis&f=false) (actually about soil arthropods) states very specifically that, "The ovipositor, with which the female lays her eggs, is homologous to the male's penis.".

Comment: That is the very best explanation for why male bees do not have stingers (which I have been asking myself on several occasions). Thanks!